# Samsung Galaxy Discover SCH-R740C running 4.0.4 fails the JB 4.1 update

Tags: updates

Our service provider *cricket* has now released the 4.1 JB update. My friend and I have the same phone, and got the message to update at the same time. His went thru no issue – but mine downloads, starts installing, and then my poor little Droid falls over with an "E sig Verification fail" – and stops the install.

I've downloaded the zip and tried to do from the recovery, and same thing. Is there a way to bypass/shut off this evil thing?

and im running everything stock!!!! NO ROOTS OR FANCY SMANCHY ROMS OR RECOVERYS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some searches to try and help some losts souls with this little phone, there is a download available on several other forums that will update this phone via Odin tar files to a 'stock' 4.1.2 firmware, it's a tool release directly from Samsung and it's available on their website.

[XDA Developer thread for CWM on the SCH-R740c](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2617484&page=1)

[Samsung download page for upgrade utility](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-R740YBACRI)

Comment: thank you so very much... altho.. i have to admit.. i was scared to death ... didnt do to badly til after the reboot... my keyboard is gone , and now i cant figure that out LOL. thank you again tho.. it did work for a bit... cricket can kiss my grits.. its a 50 dollar phone lol void the warranty.. no biggie , go buy a new one, WHICH REMINDS ME!! FOR THOSE OF YOU GETTING THIS MODEL FROM THE LOCAL WALMART OR SUCH... TAKE IT HOME, TURN IT ON... DONT ACTIVATE UNTIL AFTER YOU GET ALL YOUR STUFF IN AND THE SOFTWARE UPDATE DONE... OR YOU WILL BE LIKE ME, MY FRIEND DID HIS THAT WAY.. HES GOT NO ISSUES